# VBA Variable inside formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following code

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-54]C[-14]:R[-54]C[90],RC[-4])"
```

I want to replace 90 with a variable "total", I tried this but didn't work:

```
Dim total  as Integer
total=Inputbox("Enter a number")
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-54]C[-14]:R[-54]C[ " & total & " ],RC[-4])"
```

Ty for your help

Answer (score 2):

you need to remove the spaces in the bracket.

```
Dim total  as Integer
total=Inputbox("Enter a number")
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-54]C[-14]:R[-54]C[" & total & "],RC[-4])"
```